# ssl.SSLCertVerificationError for flask application OAuth login with keycloak

Tags: python, ssl, flask, kubernetes, keycloak

I have referred a sample hello-world flask app integrated with key-cloak login from https://gist.github.com/thomasdarimont/145dc9aa857b831ff2eff221b79d179a

My client-secrets.json is as follows:

```
{
    "web": {
        "issuer": "https://keycloak-keycloak.router.default.svc.cluster.local.167.254.224.26.nip.io/auth/realms/myrealm",
        "auth_uri": "https://keycloak-keycloak.router.default.svc.cluster.local.167.254.224.26.nip.io/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
        "client_id": "myclient",
        "client_secret": "****",
        "redirect_uris": [
            "https://167.254.224.26:30397/*"
        ],
        "userinfo_uri": "https://keycloak-keycloak.router.default.svc.cluster.local.167.254.224.26.nip.io/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
        "token_uri": "https://keycloak-keycloak.router.default.svc.cluster.local.167.254.224.26.nip.io/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token",
        "token_introspection_uri": "https://keycloak-keycloak.router.default.svc.cluster.local.167.254.224.26.nip.io/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect"
    }
}
```

When I run `python app.py` it runs successfully but once I browse the app url and click on login, it takes me to keycloack login page, after I enter my credentials I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_oidc/__init__.py", line 657, in _oidc_callback
    plainreturn, data = self._process_callback('destination')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_oidc/__init__.py", line 689, in _process_callback
    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 2054, in step2_exchange
    http, self.token_uri, method='POST', body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 282, in request
    connection_type=connection_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1994, in request
    cachekey,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1651, in _request
    conn, request_uri, method, body, headers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1557, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1326, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=self.host)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1091)
```

I suspected this might be due to my key-cloack server is https and flask app is http and hence I have  have modified the [app.py](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/thomasdarimont/145dc9aa857b831ff2eff221b79d179a/raw/a72a9462b2bd693913efba86cbc74f87c043121d/app.py) to be https:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=True, ssl_context='adhoc')
```

But even after making the flask app https, the issue remains the same.

Note since im running this application in containers , I have exposed the 8000 port to Nodeport i.e 30397 , hence the app url is : `https://167.254.224.26:30397`

Comment: have u created Realm for the same ?

Comment: yes i have created a realm. when I browse the issuer url , i get a json response.

Answer (score 4):

That's a [problem of flask-oidc](https://github.com/puiterwijk/flask-oidc/issues/52). It uses httplib2, which offers `disable_ssl_certificate_validation` option to disable ssl/tls cert verification, but unfortunately it is not configurable from the flask-oidc.

The only option is to add CA cert which was used to create TLS cert for `https://keycloak-keycloak.router.default.svc.cluster.local.167.254.224.26.nip.io` to the httplib2 ca certs:

```
cat ca-cert.crt >> [path_to_python_libs]/certifi/cacert.pem
```

Offtopic: your deployment looks like Kubernetes, so it should be easy to get `ca-cert.crt` from the cluster and copy it to right place when app is starting.

Comment: Im using openshift(okd 3.11). The keyclock is deployed using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/latest/openshift-examples/keycloak.yaml ,here i dont get any clue how to get `ca-cert.crt` or its location.

Comment: Another question regarding your answer is, the command `cat ca-cert.crt >> [path_to_python_libs]/certifi/cacert.pem` needs to be run in keycloak pod?

Comment: Command must be executed in the flask pod, not in the keycloak pod. How to get CA cert is of out of scope this question, because it depends on your Openshift configuration.

Comment: Thanks [Jan Garaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3348604/jan-garaj). Can you please guide more on `ca-cert.crt` in general, it will help me to find out its location in a openshift 3.11 cluster

Comment: @RakeshKotian unfortunately I'm not familiar with Openshift. I guess there will be mounted some secret with CA cert, which is used in the cluster to generate TLS certs. Check the doc or contact Openshift support.

Answer (score 0):

Requests session (managed by [Authlib](https://github.com/lepture/authlib)) can be configured for attributes `'proxies', 'hooks', 'stream', 'verify', 'cert', 'max_redirects', 'trust_env'` using `client_kwargs`. To disable SSL cert verification you can pass verify to False.

For example:

```
{
    "web": {
        "issuer": "https://keycloak-keycloak.router.default.svc.cluster.local.167.254.224.26.nip.io/auth/realms/myrealm",
        "auth_uri": "https://keycloak-keycloak.router.default.svc.cluster.local.167.254.224.26.nip.io/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
        "client_id": "myclient",
        "client_secret": "****",
        "redirect_uris": [
            "https://167.254.224.26:30397/*"
        ],
        "userinfo_uri": "https://keycloak-keycloak.router.default.svc.cluster.local.167.254.224.26.nip.io/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
        "token_uri": "https://keycloak-keycloak.router.default.svc.cluster.local.167.254.224.26.nip.io/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token",
        "token_introspection_uri": "https://keycloak-keycloak.router.default.svc.cluster.local.167.254.224.26.nip.io/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect"
        "client_kwargs": {"verify": False},
    }
}
```